# how to post image from website to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to upload image to facebook album using facebook api, i search alot about it if find out that the file used is from the pc..
i want to upload image to facebook album and the image path i want to get from a website ?

```
$File_path='http://example.com/sample.jpg';
$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath($FILE_PATH);

$data = $facebook->api('/'. $ALBUM_ID . '/photos', 'post', $args);
print_r($data);
```

is that possible to give a file path like i mention above?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Padawan!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have couple of severe mistakes in your code:

1. `$File_path` isn't the same as `$FILE_PATH` - remember variables are case sensitive!
2. [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) accepts path not URL and will return `false` in your case

You can only upload local files using `image` parameter, and for remote images `url` parameter should be used.

Consider using one of the next samples to achieve the desired result, for local file:

```
$facebook->api("/{$ALBUM_ID}/photos", "post", array(
  'message' => 'Photo caption',
  'image'   => '@'.realpath('./path/to/local/image/file.jpg')
));
```

And for remote file:

```
$facebook->api("/{$ALBUM_ID}/photos", "post", array(
  'message' => 'Photo caption',
  'url'   => 'http://example.com/url/of/image/file.jpg'
));
```

Comment: I am a beginner in php. If I am not wrong `/path/to/local/image/file.jpg` is the path given by `<input type='file' />` ?

Comment: @Jashwant, nope, it's the path of file located on the same machine that issuing request to Facebook. You will never get the original path from `<input type='file'>`, generally if you get your file from user you'll get either temporary file which can be directly used to upload it to Facebook, or raw data that should be saved and later used for upload...